# Ignore character encoding set by MySQL client

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I'm connecting to a MySQL server (v5.7.21) that is configured to use utf8mb4 encoding and to ignore encoding set by the client. Here are the relevant sections of my.ini config file (I'm running Windows) :

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake=FALSE
skip-character-set-client-handshake #I've added this but it has no effect
character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

My client is an ETL (Talend) which uses the JDBC driver : `mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar`.
If I set the driver property: `characterEncoding=utf8`, this overrides the character encoding set by the server (utf8mb4), as shown by this query :

```
SHOW VARIABLES 
WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%'

|=-----------------------+-----------------=|
|Variable_Name           |Value             |
|=-----------------------+-----------------=|
|character_set_client    |utf8              |
|character_set_connection|utf8              |
|character_set_database  |utf8mb4           |
|character_set_filesystem|binary            |
|character_set_results   |                  |
|character_set_server    |utf8mb4           |
|character_set_system    |utf8              |
|collation_connection    |utf8_general_ci   |
|collation_database      |utf8mb4_unicode_ci|
|collation_server        |utf8mb4_unicode_ci|
'------------------------+------------------'
```

If I don't set any driver properties on the connection, the utf8mb4 encoding is used (which is what is expected).
It seems setting `character-set-client-handshake=FALSE` and `skip-character-set-client-handshake` has no effect.
How to prevent the client from changing the encoding and force it to always use utf8mb4 ?

Comment: You seem to get the result you need by not setting the connection property, so why doesn't it suffice? Do you want to prevent misconfiguration? You cannot prevent the client to use an encoding it wants to use, it's the clients decision how it sends and reads (=interpretes) messages.

Comment: Yes, preventing misconfiguration is one of the reasons. But what bothers me is that MySQL is not behaving as the reference says: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html
"To ignore client information and use the default server character set, use --skip-character-set-client-handshake;". Why is this not working ?